# How to make audioplayer in swift?

Tags: swift, avaudioplayer

I made audio player. I realize playlist and playing audio background functionality. I need to recognize which audio played in background.

Firts I create audio player object like:

```
var mp3Player:AVAudioPlayer?=AVAudioPlayer()
var firstLoad=true
var playingType_Index=0
var speedType_Index=0
```

When I click audio from list I put clicked audio to my `selectedAudio`

```
let audios=[
    [
        "image":UIImage.fontAwesomeIconWithName(.Headphones, textColor: UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 223/255, green: 156/255, blue: 104/255, alpha: 1.0), size: CGSizeMake(35, 35)),
        "title": "Audio1",
        "desc":"Erkemin",
        "time":3,
        "src":NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("audio1", ofType: "mp3")!)
    ]
]

var selectedAudio=[
    "id":"",
    "status":"",
    "image":"",
    "title": "",
    "desc":"",
    "time":0,
    "src":""
]

func playAudio(sender:AnyObject){
    firstLoad=false
    backwardBtn.enabled=true
    step_backward.enabled=true
    play_pauseBtn.enabled=true
    stopBtn.enabled=true
    step_forward.enabled=true
    forwardBtn.enabled=true
    audioSlider.enabled=true

    selectedAudio=audios[sender.tag]
    selectedAudio["id"]=sender.tag
    selectedAudio["status"]="true"

    music()
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

I'm using `selectedAUdio` to recognize which audio now played. But when go to other view my audio continue playing but my selected audio being nil.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could have some problem like re-creation of this view: if you launch this view and `playAudio()`, `selectAudio` property is filled with your parameters but for something reason seems you re-make this view so your selectedAudio return to default values (empty strings).

If you need to stop your player with his method `stop`, you could do something like the code below:

```
func stopMp3Player() {
   if let player = mp3Player {
      if player.playing {
         player.stop()
      }     
   }
}
```

**Warning**: when you build this methods (you could also make pause) you should always check if your mp3Player is not nil to avoid crash.

About your play method I would do something like:

```
func playMp3Player(filename: String) {
        let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(filename, withExtension: nil)
        if (url == nil) {
          print("Could not find file: \(filename)")
          return
        }
        do { mp3Player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url!, fileTypeHint: nil) }
        catch let error as NSError { print(error.description) }

        if let player = mp3Player {
          player.volume = // set your volume here
          player.numberOfLoops = 0 // set the repeating
          player.prepareToPlay()
          player.play()
        }
}
```

Comment: I do not need to stop audio, i need to continue playing and get now playing audio

Comment: Look my update , hope can help you to understand what happened to your code. If you need more help try to add the code you use to move to another view